# AndroidAsyncHttp post data with 4 parameter in header and 10 in body

Tags: android-async-http

Hello all I want to use AndroidAsyncHttp for posting data to server.

for that i have 4 Parameters in header and 10 in body request i have done the following code but not working and getting null response..

```
 void callMethod()
    {


        AsyncHttpClient clinet = new AsyncHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
        httpPost.setHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "werew");
        httpPost.setHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "werweR");
        httpPost.setHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "Rwerwep");
        httpPost.setHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "werwe");

        Network.Request r = new Network.Request();
        clinet.addHeader("HEADERPRMNAME"werr");
        clinet.addHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "werwer");
        clinet.addHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "1223134");
        clinet.addHeader("HEADERPRMNAME", "wer");

//                        Headers headers1=Headers.of("HEADERPRMNAME","121");
//                        Headers headers1=Headers.of("HEADERPRMNAME","12121212");
//                        Headers headers1=Headers.of("HEADERPRMNAME","werew");
        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put("HEADERPRMNAME", 10);
        requestParams.put("HEADERPRMNAME", 1);
clinet.setUserAgent("I HAVE PASSED HERE ALSO AS STRING BUT NOT WORKED");
        clinet.post(ctx, "MYURL", requestParams, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("PPLLL" + responseString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

            }
        });
}
```

please help me out

Comment: You cannot send multiple values with same key

Comment: its different HEADERPRMNAME is different value like name pwd like that